# How to read !ruby/object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get response from Tinypass Gem below:

```
-- !ruby/object:Tinypass::Gateway::PagedList 
list: 
- !ruby/object:Tinypass::Gateway::AccessDetails 
  table: 
    :created: 1403203101
    :uid: MHC3D8N6QS
    :tags: []

    :resource_name: Dashboard content
    :rid: dashboard
    :recur: false
    :expires: 1403807901
    :aid: OQhD8dX7RX
    :amount_usd: 0.5
    :currency: USD
    :amount: 0.5
    :id: LlQpHb1XvzUP
    :user_email: visa@gmail.com
- !ruby/object:Tinypass::Gateway::AccessDetails 
  table: 
    :created: 1403082355
    :uid: H5fRXBjZ3A
    :tags: []

    :resource_name: Dashboard content
    :rid: dashboard
    :user_ref: badashah29
    :recur: false
    :expires: 1403687155
    :aid: OQhD8dX7RX
    :amount_usd: 0.99
    :currency: USD
    :amount: 0.99
    :id: ORvo1LjBs4Hk
    :user_email: badashah265@mailcatch.com
```

Can any one suggest me how to read user_ref, user_email params from this response.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like YAML, try using [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)

Comment: YAML.load ...............

Comment: Thanks to both for answer.. but i can not understand use of YAML. access_detail = Tinypass.fetch_access_detail(params)  where i got my response in access_detail variable.. then how to use YAML here?

Comment: Could you share the code actually reading your yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
require 'yaml'

# parse the yaml from the response
list = YAML.load(response)

# do something with the list
list.each {|access_detail| p access_detail }
```

Comment: Thanks @martin give me answer, but i got error "Instance of IO needed" when use YAML

Comment: I'll try to make a quick test (this was just dumped from memory) - but something like that should work.